# How to implement settings animation as in espresso code editor?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uikit

How to implement similar settings animation as in espresso.app,[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way i think is:

1. draw animation and put it to a .gif file
2. add Toolbar to your window
3. put a custom item to your toolbar, consisting of `NSImageView` and `NSButton`.
4. Add NSTrackingArea to catch `moseEntered:` and `mouseExited:`
5. set `-[NSImageView setImage:]` your gif image or in InterfaceBuilder
6. on `mouseEntered:` send
   `-[NSImageView setAnimates:YES]` on `mouseExit:` `-[NSImageView setAnimates:NO]`
7. if you need back and forth animation, make two gif files and change them

I made something like this in my Cinemagraph Wallpaper app for mac in preferences window. Just starting and stopping animation of a gif file.